# How to configure Apache Cassandra 4-Node Cluster with cassandra.yaml correctly?

Tags: python, cassandra, nodetool

So i got 4 Raspberry-Pis with Apache Cassandra on them. Static IP for each and some other configurations are already done. Each Pi can see the other 3 on the network.

The IP adresses are:

```
 1. Pi01 - 192.168.178.51
 2. Pi02 - 192.168.178.52
 3. Pi03 - 192.168.178.53
 4. Pi04 - 192.168.178.54
```

---

In my **cassandra.yaml** file i changed this variables:

```
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
initial_token: /* Pi01 has 0, the others got generated tokens */
seed_provider:
    - seeds:  "192.168.178.51"
listen_address: Droplet's IP
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch
```

---

I generated 4 Tokens with the builtin 'token-generator' in /tools/

---

**My Problem is:**

Why does after i started Pi01 it gets confusing with the tokens?

> WARN  10:24:09 Token 6436405636961323290 changing ownership from /192.168.178.52 to /192.168.178.51
>
> WARN  10:24:09 Token 7179378171345093230 changing ownership from /192.168.178.52 to /192.168.178.51
>
> WARN  10:24:09 Token 4885181782908097142 changing ownership from /192.168.178.52 to /192.168.178.51
>
> WARN  10:24:09 Token 742967880462982164 changing ownership from /192.168.178.52 to /192.168.178.51
>
> WARN  10:24:09 Token 5652804589798010165 changing ownership from /192.168.178.52 to /192.168.178.51
>
> WARN  10:24:09 Token 4400097028434728215 changing ownership from /192.168.178.52 to /192.168.178.51
>
> WARN  10:24:09 Token 1675545333640867684 changing ownership from /192.168.178.52 to /192.168.178.51
>
> WARN  10:24:09 Token -8663374480600398885 changing ownership from /192.168.178.52 to /192.168.178.51
>
> WARN  10:24:09 Token 1702469637743651899 changing ownership from /192.168.178.52 to /192.168.178.51
>
> WARN  10:24:09 Token -4986820230313833771 changing ownership from /192.168.178.52 to /192.168.178.51
>
> WARN  10:24:09 Token 5284137053355309400 changing ownership from /192.168.178.52 to /192.168.178.51
>
> WARN  10:24:09 Token -7033204945348820093 changing ownership from /192.168.178.52 to /192.168.178.51
>
> WARN  10:24:09 Token -7868759649811811191 changing ownership from /192.168.178.52 to /192.168.178.51

Answer (score 1):

While you didn't indicate your partitioner, by looking at your generated token values, I can tell that you are using the Murmur3 partitioner.  The reason that you are seeing this behavior, is that the delivered `token-generator` is designed to work with the Random partitioner.  The two partitioners use different token ranges.

Random Partitioner = 0 to 2^127

Murmur3 Partitioner = -2^63 to 2^63-1

For a 4 node cluster with the Murmur3 partitioner, you should use these token ranges:

```
aploetz@dockingBay94:~/scripts$ python murmur3Cluster.py 
How many nodes are in your cluster? 4
node 0: -9223372036854775808
node 1: -4611686018427387904
node 2: 0
node 3: 4611686018427387904
```

FYI- Here is the (Python) code used to compute these values:

```
import sys

if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
        num=int(sys.argv[1])
else:
        num=int(raw_input("How many nodes are in your cluster? "))
for i in range(0, num):
        print 'node %d: %d' % (i, (((2**64 / num) * i) - 2**63))
```

Additionally, if you configure your cluster using [Virtual Nodes](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeVnodesUsing_c.html), it will handle all off the token generation/management for you.

**EDIT:**  I investigated the `token-generator` tool to see if there was an option for the murmur3 partitioner.  Apparently this problem was addressed in [CASSANDRA-9300](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9300?jql=project%20%3D%20CASSANDRA%20AND%20text%20~%20token-generator).  Not sure of your Cassandra version, but the `token-generator` has a `--murmur3` flag as of versions 2.2.0, 2.1.6, and 2.0.16.  And "yes," it produces the same results as my Python code above does.